# Problem following math text

Tags: substitution

[image]

I tried the substitution but got for the second bracket one plus k squared times x squared, and why did the G term disappear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason is that it's an integral of the *form* $\sqrt{G.....}$, so the G is just a coefficient and nonessential, so they just omitted it in the next line, because they were focusing on the substitution.

Also, there is a negative sign because they are substituting $\displaystyle k^2 = -\frac{n}{m}$. Perhaps you may have accidentally forgotten to include the negative.

Comment: The minus n/m becomes positive k^2

Comment: But there's also a minus sign coming in from the $\sqrt{-m}$. I think the author meant to write $k^2=n/m$.

Comment: I suspected that as well thank you confirming :)

Comment: both of those are possibilities, just check that it doesn’t cause a dramatic difference in the final result